# How to capture all test cases in extent report?

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

I have an issue in print all test cases in extent report. I have added two test cases in testcase file but only last test case is showing in the extent report. Below is my code. I am executing the test cases using TestNG.

```
public class TC02_Login extends BaseClass {

    ExtentReports extent;
    ExtentTest logger;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void createReport() {
        ExtentHtmlReporter reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/finalReport.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.attachReporter(reporter);
    }

    @Parameters({ "userName", "password" })
    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void login(String userName, String password) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        logger = extent.createTest("Login Module");
        objSeleutils.click(objLogin.lbl_signin);
        objSeleutils.enterText(objLogin.txt_email, userName);
        objSeleutils.enterText(objLogin.txt_password, password);
        objSeleutils.click(objLogin.btn_signup);

        boolean txt_welcome = objSeleutils.existsElement(objLogin.ddl_welcome);
        Assert.assertEquals(txt_welcome, true);
    }

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void dashboard() {

        logger = extent.createTest("Dashboard Verification.");
        boolean txt_welcome = objSeleutils.existsElement(objLogin.btn_findPet);
        Assert.assertEquals(txt_welcome, false);
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown(ITestResult results) throws IOException {
        if (results.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + "Fail_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".png";
            String temp = objSeleutils.tackScreenShot(path);
            logger.fail(results.getThrowable().getMessage(), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(temp).build());
            logger.log(Status.FAIL, "Test Case Failed.");
        }

        if (results.getStatus() == ITestResult.SUCCESS) {
            String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + "Pass_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".png";
            String temp = objSeleutils.tackScreenShot(path);
            logger.log(Status.PASS, "Test Case Passed.", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(temp).build());
        }
        extent.flush();
    }
}
```

Here is my testNG file from where i am running my testcase.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Web" verbose="2">

<parameter name="browserName" value="Chrome" />
<parameter name="projectURL" value="http://sitename.com" />
<parameter name="userName" value="ashishsavaliya@gmail.com" />
<parameter name="password" value="*********" />

<test name="Test">          
        <classes>
            <class name='testCase.TC02_Login' />
        </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the logic that is in your @BeforeMethod should be in @BeforeClass or @BeforeSuite as you are re-creating the entire extent object with each new test as you have it now.

Comment: I am opening @BeforeSuite method in opening browser each time when test case execute. So what will be my code as per you are asking? It would be good if you write here or email me on ashishsavaliya56@gmail.com.

Comment: Typically you do indeed want to create the browser in the `@BeforeSuite` if you intend to use the same browser instance in all your tests, but that is also where you should instantiate your extent report object since all your tests are also going to go to one report output file.  Simply move the three lines of code that you currently have in `@BeforeMethod` to your `@BeforeSuite` and your tests should run and report properly without any other changes.

Comment: Yes correct its working now. I have set my report code in @BeforeSuite method and its working fine now. All the test cases are showing in the report. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As you are defining in BeforeMethod, It will overwrite with Last @Test. You need to pass some differentiate to have both reports.

like, You can use Count variable

```
public class TC02_Login extends BaseClass {

        ExtentReports extent;
        ExtentTest logger;
        WebDriver driver;
        int count = 1;

        @BeforeMethod
        public void createReport() {
            ExtentHtmlReporter reporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./Reports/finalReport"+ count + ".html");
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(reporter);
        }

    @AfterMethod
    public void teardown(ITestResult results) throws IOException {
    count++;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to do so. One of the way, which you can use is to invoke each Report in every @Test with there relevant Test name.